# Third part library create 78 linker error in an Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 section

Tags: ios, swift, linker, cocoapods

I've installed a Library with cocoaPods (first time that I use cocoaPod)
And since I've got a lot of error inside a "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64" section . 
The libPods.a is red inside of my project and inside the pods Product group , the Foundation.framework is red inside the pods. 
I've tried to reInstall it , to clear the project(derivedData too) , to delete libPod.a from the linked library and other stuff the problem stay the same .
My PodFile is:

platform :ios, '8.0'
pod 'MobileVLCKit'

the error are in a section Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
all the error except the five last one start like that :
  "std::
(I'm gonna give an example :   "std::basic_string, std::allocator >::find(wchar_t const*, unsigned long, unsigned long) const", referenced from:
      TagLib::String::find(TagLib::String const&, int) const in MobileVLCKit(tstring.cpp.o)
      TagLib::String::split(TagLib::String const&) const in MobileVLCKit(tstring.cpp.o))

after their is three starting like that

"VTT for std::
(

"VTT for std::basic_stringstream, std::allocator >", referenced from:
      dash::mpd::Segment::toChunk() in MobileVLCKit(libdash_plugin_la-Segment.o
)

dash::http::PersistentConnection::prepareRequest(dash::http::Chunk*) in MobileVLCKit(libdash_plugin_la-PersistentConnection.o)
      libebml::IOCallback::writeFully(void const*, unsigned long) in MobileVLCKit(IOCallback.o)
      libebml::IOCallback::readFully(void*, unsigned long) in MobileVLCKit(IOCallback.o)
      libebml::MemIOCallback::MemIOCallback(unsigned long long) in MobileVLCKit(MemIOCallback.o)
      libebml::StdIOCallback::StdIOCallback(char const*, open_mode) in MobileVLCKit(StdIOCallback.o)
      libebml::StdIOCallback::close() in MobileVLCKit(StdIOCallback.o)
      ...

)

and two like that

"vtable for std::basic_

(

dash::mpd::BasicCMParser::parseCommonAttributesElements(dash::xml::Node*, dash::mpd::CommonAttributesElements*, dash::mpd::CommonAttributesElements*) const in MobileVLCKit(libdash_plugin_la-BasicCMParser.o)

dash::mpd::BasicCMParser::handleDependencyId(dash::mpd::Representation*, dash::mpd::AdaptationSet const*, std::string const&) in MobileVLCKit(libdash_plugin_la-BasicCMParser.o)
      dash::mpd::BasicCMParser::resolveUrlTemplates(std::string&, bool&) in MobileVLCKit(libdash_plugin_la-BasicCMParser.o)
      dash::mpd::SegmentTemplate::getSourceUrl() const in MobileVLCKit(libdash_plugin_la-SegmentTemplate.o)
      dash::mpd::Segment::toChunk() in MobileVLCKit(libdash_plugin_la-Segment.o)

```
  dash::http::PersistentConnection::prepareRequest(dash::http::Chunk*) in MobileVLCKit(libdash_plugin_la-PersistentConnection.o)
  libebml::IOCallback::writeFully(void const*, unsigned long) in MobileVLCKit(IOCallback.o)
  ...
```

)

there is a note :   NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.

and at the end of the section :

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

in the very end of the warning message I've get an activity log complete with 80 error :?

thanks for reading

PS : I can't find any .m document I hope It's normal 
PS: Yes I open my project in the Workspace created by Cocoapods

Comment: Could you provide some of error messages? What symbols are undefined?

Comment: I've added some error message to my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something with CocoaPods file but it looks like your project doesn't have libstdc++ in dependencies. I see it in spec:

```
xcconfig": {
    "CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD": "c++11",
    "CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY": "libstdc++"
}
```

You need it for C++ code.

Comment: You're a genius , I've been stuck a week, everything is gone ,I don't think I would have thinked to that.

Comment: I got same problem, but with the @John Tracid's Solution doesn't resolve.